# How to find all possible pairs of the cells in a table excluding those from the same column

Tags: combinatorics

I'm reading a book "APPLIED CRYPTANALYSIS Breaking Ciphers in the Real World" by Mark Stamp and Richard M. Low. It has the next paragraph:

> Suppose an English plaintext containing **n** letters is encrypted using a
>   Vigenere cipher, with a keyword of length **k**, where, for simplicity, we assume **n** is a multiple of **k** . Now suppose that we arrange the ciphertext
>   letters into a rectangular array of **n / k** rows and **k** columns, from left to right, top to bottom. If we select two letters from different columns in the array, this would be similar to choosing from a collection of letters that is uniformly distributed, since the keyword is more-or-less “random”. In this case, the portion of pairs of identical letters is, approximately,
>   $$
> 0.03846  \binom{k}{2} \left(\frac{n}{k}\right)^2 = 0.03846 \frac{n^2(k-1)}{2k}
> $$

0.03846 - is the so called index of coincidence (the probability to choose identical letters when two random letters are picked, sort of) if all letters have the same frequency in text, consequently the probability to choose identical letters from the table (array) is 0.03846 multiplied by the amount of all letter pairs from different columns.

I just cannot understand how the amount of all the wanted pairs equals to

$$\binom{k}{2} \left(\frac{n}{k}\right)^2$$

---

The next is the amount of all pairs in one row (like at the picture). That is clear.

$$\binom{k}{2}$$                                                    [image: a schematic picture of the table and some combinations]

Also each such a pair has "a twin" in all subsequent rows, so we can multiply this amount for the number of rows $\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$:

$$\binom{k}{2} \left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$$

[image: some twin combinations in the subsequent rows in the table]

But I cannot understand how did they get the additional multiplication for $\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$?

Since there are still combinations with cells which belong to different rows, like here:

[image: some of the remaining pairs in the table]

I need to include them, but I cannot figure out how.

So could anyone please help me with this, or explain why the expression from the book is correct (I suppose it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two independent choices of a row, one for each of the columns chosen, and each of those choices has $\frac nk$ options. By the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), that makes $\frac nk\cdot\frac nk=\left(\frac nk\right)^2$.

Comment: I would like to elaborate, if you don't mind. For each combination in a row, there are (n/k) combinations in the table which contain the first element of the chosen combination and (n/k) combinations which contain the second element. So the final amount is the amount of combinations multiplied twice for the amount of rows, according to the multiplication principle

Comment: @user907860: Sorry, I can't follow that description. I don't understand how you're using the expressions "combination", "combination in a row" and "multiplied twice for the amount of rows". What isn't clear about the formulation in the answer?

Comment: it wasn't very clear, but I thought I got it. For me this **There are two independent choices of a row, one for each of the columns chosen** is not clear. What does it mean "the columns chosen"? I do not choose columns, except the columns to which each element from any combination belong. So  I have understood it this way: suppose I took the first row. I can take all combinations of the elements in it. For each of this combinations I can take a corresponding one from the other rows by replacing the first or the second element with one from every other row, hence the choice of n / k rows

Comment: and then replace the other element in the taken combination. So the total amount of combinations in the table should be the amount of combinations in a row multiplied twice for the amount of rows.

Comment: @user907860: Now I understand. If that makes it clearer for you, that's good. To me this approach of first choosing concrete elements and then changing their rows seems a bit roundabout; to my mind it's clearer to choose columns and rows separately: $\binom k2$ choices for pairs of distinct columns and $\frac nk$ choices corresponding to each of the columns. If you prefer thinking in terms of concrete elements right away, that's also fine.